# google oauth2 issue with application access

Tags: c, oauth-2.0, gmail

I have been working on a C server implementation of oauth2 gmail access successfully and got it working for quite some time now (around 6 months ago).

The way my server works is that every-time I want to access a mailbox, I issue a new access token with a previously created refresh token. The refresh token was granted via an initialization phase where my application was given consent by the client account that owns the mailbox.

I had two mailboxes set like that for the last six months and worked perfectly. I could access and read all the emails with oauth2 and imap.

As of yesterday, around the same time (taken from my logs) both of these accounts had my application (from the consent initialization) removed from them. No user has done that manually.

The json I receive is this:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

I know that if I go through the initialization phase (consent and generation of a new refresh token) I will be able to access the inboxes normally, but this is not preferable as clients must receive their messages without delays and manual labor.

From what I have read from a previous question is that refresh tokens should not be treated as if they expire (unless manually revoked / password change).

My question is how could this be possible? Did I miss some kind of warning or policy? Is there some step I missed?

Thanks in advance

---

16-Jul-20

I will add some more information,

a) my application that was granted consent has not been verified (still waiting) by google.

b) never at any point did I do any work for automated google messages regarding privacy / security checks for that account (e.g. "Help strengthen the security of your Google Account" that where received more than 3 months ago in these accounts as it is out of my scope)

thanks again in advance

Comment: I think it is more revoked than expired in your case, google asks sometime to relog, for example when I move to another country

Comment: You are right, I have went through this link:


https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/increased-account-security-via-oauth-2-0-token-revocation


But still it doesn't give me an answer on how this was done without any user interaction (e.g password change or revoking access to the application manually from the google account options)